# How to efficiently find multimap k-itemset frequency

Tags: list-manipulation, data-mining

I am doing this to learn association rules. The data `d` is in format `{id, value}`, for example:

```
{{0, 29}, {1, 30}, {1, 31}, {1, 32}, {2, 33}, {2, 34}, {2, 35}, {3, 36}, {3, 37}, {3, 38},
 {3, 39}, {3, 40}, {3, 41}, {3, 42}, {3, 43}, {3, 44}, {3, 45}, {3, 46}, {4, 38}, {4, 39},
 {4, 47}, {4, 48}, {5, 38}, {5, 39}, {5, 48}}
```

[Bigger data example](https://raw.github.com/gist/4040530/fb175e2134559351354572a4aa0554d462cae31b/gistfile1.txt) (task I am using it for has x100 amount data)

I want to find number of id's that contain values `{x, y}` and `P(x|y)`. Something like:

```
Contains[d_, x_] := Take[Transpose[Select[d, #[[2]] == x &]], 1][[1]]
ContainsBoth[d_, x_, y_] := Length[Intersection[Contains[d, x], Contains[d, y]]]
ProbabilityOfXGivenY[d_, x_, y_] := ContainsBoth[d, x, y]/Length[Contains[d, y]]
```

I would like to print out a table or export into a file

[image]

As my effort, I can write a brute force solution, that works well for input size of 100 instances.

```
GetRow[d_, {x_, y_}] := {x, y, ContainsBoth[d, x, y], 
  100 ProbabilityOfXGivenY[d, x, y] // N, 
  100 ProbabilityOfXGivenY[d, y, x] // N}
Select[GetRow[d, #] & /@ 
  Select[Tuples[DeleteDuplicates[Transpose[d][[2]]], 2], 
    (#[[1]] < #[[2]]) &], #[[3]] > 1 &];
TableForm[%, TableHeadings -> {Automatic, {"x", "y", "\[Exists]{x,y}", "P(x|y)", "P(y|x)"}}]
```

**edit**: I slightly improved my bruteforce solution:

```
d = Import["https://raw.github.com/gist/4040530/
  fb175e2134559351354572a4aa0554d462cae31b/gistfile1.txt", "Package"];
data = Take[d, 100000];

MultiSet[hm_, key_, value_] := hm[key] = value;
ContainsBoth[hm_, x_, y_] := Length[Intersection[MS[x], MS[y]]]
P[hm_, x_, y_] := 100 (ContainsBoth[hm, x, y]/Length[hm[y]])
GetRow[d_, {x_, y_}] := {x, y, ContainsBoth[d, x, y], P[d, x, y] // N, P[d, y, x] // N}

Timing[
 Clear[MS];
 MultiSet[MS, #[[1, 2]], #[[All, 1]]] & /@ SplitBy[SortBy[data, Last], Last];
 parsedData = {#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} & /@ SplitBy[SortBy[data, First], First];
 nrnodes = Length[pairs = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ 
   parsedData[[All, 2]], 1]]];
 result = GetRow[MS, #] & /@ pairs;
 nrnodes]
```

This completes in 41.091 s on my computer.

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "datax.csv"}], Reverse[SortBy[result, #[[3]] &]]]
```

Comment: I suspect your question might be, is there a more efficient method ?

Comment: Well the `Select[Tuples[DeleteDuplicates` and `Take[Transpose[Select[d, #[[2]] == x &]], 1][[1]]` are like the dumbest things ever, but I am not sure how to store the data in Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Edited to respond to comments: the algorithm has been changed and evidence added to show how it reproduces the example in the question.)

---

Why not exploit built-in procedures to do this work?  I refer to matrix multiplication (`Dot`) for the counting and `SparseArray` for managing its results.  These will do fine given that $x$ and $y$ are integers falling within reasonable ranges.  To make life easy, I add $1$ to their values (because `SparseArray` cannot index from $0$) and later subtract $1$--watch for these moves.

Also, it appears that trivial co-occurrences are not to be reported: only table entries where the third column exceeds $1$ should be output.

```
a = SparseArray[data + 1 -> ConstantArray[1, Length[data]]];
colsums = Total /@ Transpose[a];
x = Union[data[[All, 2]]] + 1;
x = Select[{x, colsums[[x]]}\[Transpose], Last[#] > 1 & ][[All, 1]];
b = a[[All, x]]\[Transpose] . a[[All, x]]
```

All the needed information is contained in matrix `b`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
    results = Flatten[ParallelTable[{x[[i]] - 1, x[[j]] - 1, b[[i, j]], 
      b[[i, j]] / b[[j, j]], b[[i, j]] / b[[i, i]]}, 
     {i, 1, Length[x] - 1}, {j, i + 1, Length[x]}], 1];]
```

> {66.3937166, Null}

As an example of how this works, let's consider the data in the question:

```
data = {{0, 29}, {1, 30}, {1, 31}, {1, 32}, {2, 33}, {2, 34}, {2, 35}, {3, 36}, {3, 37}, {3, 38}, {3, 39}, {3, 40}, {3, 41}, {3, 42}, {3, 43}, {3, 44}, {3, 45}, {3, 46}, {4, 38}, {4, 39}, {4, 47}, {4, 48}, {5, 38}, {5, 39}, {5, 48}};
```

The `a` and `b` matrices look like these:

```
ArrayPlot[a]
```

[image: Array a]

```
ArrayPlot[b]
```

[image: ArrayP b]

A tabulation of `results` shows how the output in the question is correctly reproduced:

```
TableForm[results, TableHeadings -> {Range[Length[results]], {"x", "y", "Pairs", "x|y", "y|x"}}]
```

[image: Table]

Comment: `Tally` does not seem to do any reduction of the data, i.e. `Length[data] == Length[Tally[data]]`.

Comment: @Sasha Try it--look at the output.  Or experiment with a subset of the data. I can't speak to what's in the data, of course: if it happens to be the case that each ordered pair occurs just once, you can eliminate `Tally`. For the general problem as stated (and illustrated), tallying seems like an essential step.

Comment: I see, the intent of `Tally` was to help get to the `SparseArray` rules. You could have done `SparseArray[Thread[(1+data)->1]]` instead. I'm not nitpicking, just trying to understand what you did.

Comment: @Sasha That's fine--I really appreciate the review, because I'm concerned I may have overlooked something crucial (my solution looks too simple!)  For an example of why `Tally` might be needed, consider processing an artificial dataset such as `data = RandomInteger[MultivariatePoissonDistribution[30, {20, 40}], 100000]`.  Note how the output of `Tally` (in variable `t`) is needed at the end.

Comment: That is efficient code. However it is completely wrong or I miss to understand what you did. Maybe this will help, in case of `data = Take[data, 1000];` the result I am looking for looks like: http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/8020/newsql.png.

Comment: Margus, An indication of *how* this is "completely wrong" would be appreciated. (My code produces a table that looks qualitatively like yours.) Could you perhaps provide a small dataset along with the expected output? Or maybe a clear description of what your question is, one that does not require us to parse your code to figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

Read in you data:

```
data = Import[
   "https://raw.github.com/gist/4040530/\
fb175e2134559351354572a4aa0554d462cae31b/gistfile1.txt", "Package"];
```

Parse the list of `{id,value}` into the aggregated list `{{id1, valuesList1},{id2,valuesList2},...}}`.

```
parsedData = {#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} & /@ 
   SplitBy[SortBy[data, First], First];
```

We can now rebuild your function `GetRow` to compute the count and conditional probabilities in one go for efficiency:

```
oGetRow[pd_, {x_, y_}] := 
 Block[{mask = 
    Cases[pd, {id_, vals_} :> 
      Block[{h1 = MemberQ[vals, x], 
        h2 = MemberQ[vals, y]}, {Boole[h1], Boole[h2]} /; h1 || h2]], 
   both},
  both = Count[mask, {1, 1}];
  If[both > 1,
   {x, y, both, 100. both/Count[mask[[All, 2]], 1], 
    100. both/Count[mask[[All, 1]], 1]},
   {x, y, both, 0, 0}
   ]
  ]
```

Selecting pairs of values, where the count is greater than 0 can be done much more efficiently:

```
In[14]:= Length[
 pairs = DeleteDuplicates[
   Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ parsedData[[All, 2]], 1]]]

Out[14]= 565322
```

You original attempt would need to go through approximately 3*10^8 pairs, vast majority of which would need to be discarded.

Now going through the entire data set takes some time, so it can use `ParallelMap`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Cases[
    ParallelMap[oGetRow[parsedData, #] &, pairs], {_, _, 
     Except[0 | 1], _, _}];]
```

Using 4 cores this takes over 15 minutes.

So I decided to get a subset of pairs to estimate the timing.

```
In[18]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Cases[
    ParallelMap[oGetRow[parsedData, #] &, pairs[[;; 1000]]], {_, _, 
     Except[0 | 1], _, _}];]

Out[18]= {42.486000, Null}
```

Thus the projected time on a 4-core machine is almost 7 hours, so within reach of an overnight computation.

```
In[21]:= 42.486 565/3600.

Out[21]= 6.66794
```

---

Using 16-core machine it finished much faster.

```
In[5]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Cases[
    ParallelMap[oGetRow[parsedData, #] &, pairs], {_, _, 
     Except[0 | 1], _, _}];]                        


Out[5]= {2271.047723, Null}

In[6]:= Length[res]

Out[6]= 76660

In[7]:= Export["~/res.m", res]

Out[7]= ~/res.m
```

If you are interested in the output, let me know.

Comment: It takes me a bit to follow but, ˇLength[pairs = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ parsedData[[All, 2]], 1]]]ˇ in this case is 565322 and not 5357.

Comment: My bad. The result of my evaluation was for the subset of data. I will correct that

Comment: @Margus It looks like processing the entire data-set will require some 7 hours of a 4-core machine (mine is few years old laptop).